# Можно ли программно менять доступ к редактированию Google Spreadsheets листов или ячеек?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

С таблицей, в которой организованы связанные выпадающие списки, постоянно работает несколько сотрудников.
Есть ли способ запретить редактирование строки для других пользователей, как только первый из них начал её редактирование?
И, соответственно, снять запрет, как только редактирование будет закончено?

Comment: Сформулируйте свой вопрос в формате задачи, которую вы уже решаете. Если вы к ней даже не приступили, то зачем спрашивать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программно можно сделать защиту диапазона или листа

- Пример [Sheets
  API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/ranges)
- Пример
  [Apps
  Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

Но отслеживать начало редактирования и последующая защита - не самая лучшая идея. Вероятно, технически она достижима, но затраты на создание такой программы неадекватно непропорциональны цели.

С другой стороны, возможен такой процесс:

- Пользователь выбирает, что он будет редактировать
- Система открывает ему доступ на заданную строку

Дополнительные шаги в системе могут только усугубить ситуацию с рабочим процессом.